# My app doesn't save data in local storage after login with an api

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my app, I'm login with an api, that returns a token and the username. I want to save both in local storage. The username, I want to show it later in the app.

It logins, but doesn't save the data.

I'm using Ionic 4 with angular.

*app.component.ts*:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
        if (state) {
          this.authService.storage.get('nameLogued').then((val) => {
            this.nameOfUser = val;
          })
          this.router.navigate(['members', 'home']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

*app.component.html*:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
        {{nameOfUser}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

*authentication.service.ts*:

```
login(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.global.urlAPI + 'api/login', user);
 }
```

*login.page.ts*:

```
login(form) {
    this.authService.login(form).subscribe(data => {
      this.storage.set(this.global.token_key, data['token']);
      this.storage.set('nameLogued', data['user'].name);
      this.authService.authenticationState.next(true);
      this.login_form = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: new FormControl(''),
        password: new FormControl('')
      })
    }, (error => {
      this.toast.showToastError('There is wrong data.');
    }));
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is the code to store data in local storage i cant see it any where

Comment: In the _login.page.ts_, there where it says `this.storage.set('nameLogued', data['user']name);`

this.storage is `private storage: Storage;`

Comment: look at the example i have given you can use like that make on service where you can set and get

Comment: You have to import storage in in you `app.component.ts` as well..
and do same as you did in login `private storage: Storage`. and then get it like `this.storage.get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using events.publishing:

*login.page.ts*

```
login(form) {
    this.loading.presentLoading('Iniciando sesion...');
    this.authService.login(form).subscribe(data => {
      this.storage.set(this.global.token_key, data['token']);
      this.storage.set('nameLogued', data['user'].name);
      this.authService.authenticationState.next(true);
      this.login_form = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: new FormControl(''),
        password: new FormControl('')
      });
      this.events.publish('user:login', data['user']);
      this.loadingController.dismiss();
    }, (error => {
      this.toast.showToastError('Los datos ingresados son incorrectos.');
      this.loadingController.dismiss();
    }));
  }
```

*app.component.ts*

```
constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private storage: Storage,
    public events: Events
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    events.subscribe('user:login', (user) => {
      this.nameOfUser = user.name;
    });
  }

initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.storage.get('nameLogued').then((val) => {
        this.nameOfUser = val;
      })
      this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
        if (state) {
          this.router.navigate(['members', 'home']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Store Data**

```
const credentialsKey = 'currentUser'; 
login(loginData: Login): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('Usermaster/Authenticate', loginData).pipe(
      tap(
        function (data) {
          const storage = loginData.remember ? localStorage : sessionStorage;
          storage.setItem(credentialsKey, JSON.stringify(data));
          return data;
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

**To Fetch Data From Stored Value**

```
 private getUser() {
    const savedCredentials = sessionStorage.getItem(credentialsKey) || localStorage.getItem(credentialsKey);
    return JSON.parse(savedCredentials);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use any third library just use browser command to set and get use LocalStorage.setItem() to set and LocalStorage.getItem() to get
I.e.

```
this.rest.login(user, data => {
      if (data.Data != null) {
        this.rest.loadingDismiss();
        this.rest.presentToast('You have logged in');
        localStorage.setItem('UserKey', data.Data.UserKey);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `app.component.ts`

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';  // Import storage

constructor(private storage: Storage) { }  // inject in your constructor

initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
        if (state) {
          this.storage.get('nameLogued').then((val) => {  // use it like this. 
            this.nameOfUser = val;
          })
          this.router.navigate(['members', 'home']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Importing it from `authService` is causing this issue.

Comment: I did it, but doesn´t solve the problem... I think is something of the async of storage... Don´t know wich is the best way to get data from storage...